# How do pseudo elements make the current div behave?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

These pseudo elements have been tripping me up for sometime now, and I a little confused about it all.

In this example:

```
div::before {
  content: "hi";
}
```

It is injecting **hi** before any HTML content. I understand with a clearfix, you will need to clear the float.

```
.clear:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: -1px
     }
```

However here:

```
.box-content::before {
     display: inline-block;
     content: " "
}
```

Is the above the same as:

```
.box-content {
     display: inline-block;
     /* rest of the styles here */
}
```

---

I saw recently:

```
header::after, section::after, article::after, footer::after, header::before, section::before, article::before, footer::before {
    content: " ";
    display: table
}
```

Would this be **essentially the same** as having all those different styles, but with a `display: table;` style added individually to each element? Seeing as no `content: " ";` is being added to the div.

What would happen if you had a `float:left` added to a div say:

```
.larger-box-content {
      float: left
}

.larger-box-content::before {
      display: table;
      content: " "
}
```

In the above example, is this some kind of a hack as the div in question is being floated, why would you need to `display: table;` ::before the div?

How do ::before and ::after styles affect the current div?

Comment: You are referring to `pseudo-elements`, not `pseudo-classes`. `Pseudo-classes` have a single colon (`:hover`, `:target`, `:focus`, `nth-of-type(2n)`). Pseudo-elements have a double-colon (`::before`, `::after`).

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question. Slowly getting there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:before` is actually not a [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes), but it is a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

> A CSS **pseudo-element** is a keyword added to a selector that lets you style a specific part of the selected element(s).

In that link, it also explains

> `::before` creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property.

The pseudo elements' styling does not affect the styling of the elements they are attached to. They could however affect the placement or the (end-result) appearance of that element.

Application of pseudo elements vary from adding content, to clearing floats to creating icons without using images: https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

**UPDATE**

In response to your question regarding `::before` with style `display: table`, as a short answer, yes it is a *clearfix* hack.

These articles can give you more info about the need for *clearfix* and some history behind it:

- [Understanding the Humble Clearfix](http://www.fuseinteractive.ca/blog/understanding-humble-clearfix)
- [The Clearfix: Force an Element To Self-Clear its Children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. In response to my updated question: Why is `display: table;` on the ::before required and seen nowdays on the web? Is it like a little hack for floating elements?

Comment: Hi @davvy, please see my update. It is not really *required*. It is there if you need it as it solves specific issues on consistency in layout across different browsers.

Comment: Hi @Frank! Me again... So I saw a website yesterday that for some reason was styling the body tag using a body::before. Here it is: `body::before {
    background-color: #00ffef;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    transition: height .6s cubic-bezier(.55,.055,.675,.19);
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 200;` Why may they do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @davvv, to be honest, that CSS does not make sense to me. It is adding a pseudo element with no visibility, 0 opacity, 0 height and 0 width. That does not mean it is wrong. It just means, without further context, I can't tell what it is trying to do. You might want to ask another question and give more info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an infographic:

`<` [ELEMENT BEGINS] [`::before`] `ELEMENT CORE` [`::after`] [ELEMENT ENDS] `>`

The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements ***aren't*** literally before and after the element in question.

They are at the very start of the element before the "element core" and at the very end of the element after the "element core".

The element will not inherit styles from its child pseudo-elements

If you need an element to have a red background color and you give its `::before` pseudo-element a red background color, that will not give the element a red background color.

Comment: Yes, items are added before any HTML content or after the HTML content, but for another example could you style the entire div on the ::before element? Or does the **main** div need to be styled?

Comment: The element will not inherit styles from its child pseudo-elements, no.